# Confluent KSQL "Register a stream or table for this topic" doesn't populate topic fields

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-cloud

I have 4 topics where I was able to successfully stream data to, and their schemas look good.

But after clicking a topic > "Query in KSQL", I noticed only 1 of them populates the "Field(s) you'd like to include in your STREAM". The other 3 show up blank like so:

[image]

I noticed the topic that was able to populate the KSQL fields has a surrogate int primary key called `id` whereas the ones that don't work have a natural string primary key called `boxId` e.g. `"ABC123"`, if that has anything to do with it?

What am I missing to get those fields to populate?

Comment: Can u please elaborate on what type of Store is being used ... such as a KStream or a KTable?

Comment: do you have a defined schema for the key? I mean do you use String, Int, Long or Avro to serialise keys?

Comment: @atkayla What serialisation format are you using for the key and the value? Can you share the schema?

Comment: Topic to Table. Schema is defined for key. Avro. But I switched from `AvroConverter` to `JsonConverter` with `schemas.enable=false` and everything suddenly worked.